# How to get the 7 days in a week with a currentDate in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, dayofweek, weekday

(first, sorry for my bad english, i'm a beginner)

I have a chart of percent by date. I would like to display every day of the current week in the x-axis.

So, i tried to find how to get the seven days of the week.
that's what i have :

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();//to set first day on monday, not on sunday, first+1 :

var firstday = (new Date(curr.setDate(first+1))).toString();

for(var i = 1;i<7;i++){
var next = first + i;
var nextday = (new Date(curr.setDate(next))).toString();
alert(nextday);
}
```

the alert begins well...until the end of the month. That's what i got :

```
1 : "Mon 27 Feb 2012 ..."
2 : "Tue 28 Feb 2012 ..."
3 : "Wed 29 Feb 2012 ..."
4 : "Thu 01 Mar 2012 ..."
5 : "Sat 31 Mar 2012 ..."
6 : "Sun 01 Apr 2012 ..."
```

So, as you can see, it switches the friday and... strangely it switch to the good date...4 weeks later...

So, do you have a better solution for me, or maybe you could just help me and say what is the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you have fallen into one of the numerous traps of object mutation. :)

The problem is that, in the line "var nextday = ...", you are changing the date saved in "curr" on every iteration by calling *setDate()*. That is no problem as long as *next* is within the range of the current month; *curr.setDate(next)* is equivalent to going forward one in this case.

The problems begin when *next* reaches 30. There is no February 30, so *setDate()* wraps around to the next month, yielding the 1st of March - so far so good. Unfortunately, the next iteration calls *curr.setDate(31)*, and as *curr* is the 1st of March (remember that the object referenced by *curr* is changed in each iteration), we get... March 31! The other strange values can be explained the same way.

A way to fix this is to copy *curr* on each iteration and **then** call setDate(), like so:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var next = new Date(curr.getTime());
    next.setDate(first + i);
    alert(next.toString());
}
```

Comment: thank you @denisw , you explained what was wrong in a really pedagog way, i understood :), and you helped me to fix the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all,
I understood that everytime i change the `curr` value and that was the problem.
All your solutions are working, but i'll prefer the simplest one, the one from @denisw, which I copy there for anybody else with the same problem :

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
var firstday = (new Date(curr.setDate(first+1))).toString();
for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
   var next = new Date(curr.getTime());
   next.setDate(first+i);
   alert(next.toString());                            
}
```

Once again, thank you all, for your quick answers and your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `date` and `day`. The former goes from 1 to 28..31 and the latter from 0 to 6. What should the Date type do if you set the date to -3?

The solution is to convert all values to milliseconds.

```
var ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000*60*60*24;

var curr = new Date();

// Get offset to first day of week
// Note: Depending on your locale, 0 can be Sunday or Monday.
var offset = curr.getDay() * ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS;

// Date at the start of week; note that hours, minutes and seconds are != 0
var start = new Date( curr.getTime() - offset );

for( var i=0; i<7; i++ ) {
    var nextDay = new Date( start.getTime() + ( i * ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS ) );
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually JS handles over-/underflow on dates quite fine. For example, `alert(new Date(2012, 2 /*Mar*/, -1));` will return `Feb 28, 2012` and  `alert(new Date(2012, 1 /*Feb*/, 30));` is `Mar 1, 2012`.

Comment: i didn't want to pass by this way (i knew it exists). but thank you very much though, you explained me your way quite well and maybe later i'll use it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modifying your `curr` date and creating a new date at the same time. There are two ways to do this:

Either never modifiy your `curr` date object and create new Dates:

```
var msInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

function addDays(date, days) {
  return new Date(date.getTime() + days * msInDay);        
}

var curr = new Date();

var first = addDays(curr, -curr.getDay() + 1);

alert(first);

for(var i = 1; i<7; i++) {
    var next = addDays(first, i);
    alert(next);
}
```

Or modify your `curr` date object consistently:

```
var curr = new Date();

curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + 1);

alert(curr);

for(var i = 1; i<7; i++) {
    curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + 1);
    alert(curr);
}

​
```

Comment: thanks for both ways, i tried the one-line version of @denisw, but yours is quite understandable! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let curr = new Date;
let week = []

for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i 
  let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
  week.push(day)
}
console.log('week:', week);
```

jsfidde: https://jsfiddle.net/sinh_nguyen/v9kszn2h/4/